# How to reference single column that has unique constraint with another column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, foreign-keys, constraints

I have this "Types" table

```
+-----------+--------+
| RefTypeID | TypeID |
+-----------+--------+
| 1         | 1      |
| 1         | 2      |
| 1         | 3      |
| 2         | 2      |
| 2         | 4      |
| 3         | 5      |
+-----------+--------+
```

As the couple of values in each row won't be repeated, I created a unique constraint including both columns.

I have another table (Prymes) that looks like this

```
+---------+-----------+--------------------+
| PrymeID | RefTypeID | ***More Columns*** |
+---------+-----------+--------------------+
| 1       | 2         |         ***        |
| 2       | 2         |         ***        | 
| 3       | 3         |         ***        |
| 4       | 1         |         ***        |
| 5       | 1         |         ***        |
| 6       | 3         |         ***        |
+---------+-----------+--------------------+
```

And I want to create a foreign key in Prymes that references just the RefTypeID column in Types, but due to the constraint the relation must include two columns in Prymes and the two columns in Keys.

Is there any way I can create the relation using just the RefTypeID column in both tables?

Comment: What have you tried, and why this doesn't works (error message)?

Comment: @DanielBlais I tried just to remove the constraint in the Types table, but the foreign key must reference a column (or group of columns) with an unique constraint, or defined as primary keys. I have no clue about what else should I try

Comment: That what I tought.  It must references unique key (unique column or unique composite key).  You have to create another table, where RefTypeID is unique.

Comment: This is not a valid foreign key.

Comment: A FK says values appear elsewhere as a PK. You don't have that. So you don't want a FK. What *do* you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

You can only create a foreign key to **all** columns of a primary key or unique key. You can't use a partial because there is no guarantee that a single column of a multi-column unique key uniquely identifies a row (and it doesn't as shown in your example data).

In other words, you'll need a table with the unique `RefTypeId`s and make `RefTypeId` the primary key of that table and reference that from both `Types` and `Prymes` with a foreign key.

Comment: Or, alternatively, you can create a 1-column surrogate key in the `Types` table (`identity` would do, for example), and reference that key with FK from `Prymes`. This would save the hassle of creating a separate single-column table, which normally brings more questions and confusion rather than clarity.

Comment: @RogerWolf Maybe, but I assume that that `RefTypeId` as more meaning in the actual model and therefor could have more information associated with it, otherwise its presence in `Types` and in `Prymes` doesn't make much sense either, and pointing from `Prymes` to a surrogate key of `Types` would be the same as adding `TypeId` to `Prymes`, and therefor change the meaning (as it would no longer point to the concept of `RefType` (whatever that is), but to a specific `Type` (combination of `RefTypeId` and `TypeId`).